# ValueError: The RNN cell should have an attribute `state_size` (tuple of integers, one integer per RNN state)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i'm trying to migrate here from tensorflow 1.x to tensorflow 2.2.0 which from from compat to Keras

```
class Model:
    def __init__(
        self,
        learning_rate,
        num_layers,
        size,
        size_layer,
        output_size,
        forget_bias = 0.1,
    ):
        def lstm_cell(size_layer):
            return tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(size_layer)

        rnn_cells = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)]
        )
        self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, size))
        self.Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, output_size))

        drop = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(
            rnn_cells, forget_bias
        )

        self.hidden_layer = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(
            tf.float32, (None, num_layers * 2 * size_layer)
        )
        self.outputs, self.last_state = tf.keras.layers.RNN(
            drop, self.X, self.hidden_layer, dtype = tf.float32
        )
        self.logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(self.outputs[-1], output_size)
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.Y - self.logits))
        self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
            self.cost
        )
```

this is my code model, and the error is at :

```
self.outputs, self.last_state = tf.keras.layers.RNN(
            drop, self.X, self.hidden_layer, dtype = tf.float32
        )
```

the error is :

```
ValueError: The RNN cell should have an attribute `state_size` (tuple of integers, one integer per RNN state).
```

what does the code look like to solve it? thank you very much